# How to save single record using Lightning:recordEditform inside aura:iteration? I am able to save all the records by using forEach in JS Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration, lightning-recordeditform

Component:

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.oppStageList}" var="opp"><lightning:recordEditForm aura:id = "StageChange" recordId ="{!opp.Id}" objectApiName ="Opportunity" onsuccess ="{!c.handleSuccess}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}">

                        <lightning:messages />
                        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-medium" size="1">
                                <lightning:outputField aura:id="Owner" fieldName="OwnerId" variant="label-hidden"/>
                            </lightning:layoutItem>
                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-medium" size="1">
                                <lightning:outputField aura:id="Name" fieldName="Name" variant="label-hidden"/>
                            </lightning:layoutItem>

                            </lightning:layoutItem>
                            <lightning:inputField aura:id="approved" fieldName="Stage_Approved__c" variant="label-hidden" class="HideFields"/>
                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="2">
                                <div>
                                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="success" name="save" label="Approve" type="submit" class="slds-m-right_x-small"/>
                                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="destructive" type="submit" name="save" label="Reject" />
                                </div>
                            </lightning:layoutItem>
                        </lightning:layout>
                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </aura:iteration>
```

JS controller:

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    //event.preventDefault(); // stop form submission
    var eventFields = event.getParam('fields');
    eventFields["Stage_Approved__c"] = true;
    //component.find('StageChange').submit(eventFields);
    component.find("StageChange").forEach( form =>{
        form.submit(eventFields);
    });
    component.set('v.showSpinner', true);
},

handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.showSpinner', false);
}
```

Comment: which single record you want to submit? like if  u have 10 items in `v.oppStageList`  attribute which one you want to submit?

Comment: @sdandamud1: it can be any record based on the save action out of 10. So how will I identify which one to save? The one in the JS controller where I am using forEach saves all the records if I clicked on any of the save action on any of the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller markup, I am running for-loop on **component.find("StageChange")** and break it after one iteration. **event.getParam('fields');** returns the row where the button has been pressed. You don't need to submit everything in **component.find("StageChange")** list.

```
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var eventfields= event.getParam('fields');
    for(var key in component.find("StageChange")){
        component.find("StageChange")[key].submit(eventfields);
        break;
    }        
},
```

Comment: I am getting eventFields["Id"] and  event.getSource().get("v.name") bopth as 'undefined'

Comment: @hardikace29 please find the updated code.

Comment: how do I use selectedrecordid in handleSubmit? @sanket kumar

Comment: @hardikace29 I have updated the code. You don't need the aura:attribute at all.

Comment: thanks! That worked @Sanket